# Magento2 - Customer Login Area just a blank screen

Tags: magento2, customer-account

This morning while trying to log into the Magento2 "My Account or Sign in" area the screen just returns a blank white page. We didn't change anything.

Comment: Please active developer mode and check error. Post error on question.

Comment: It appears to be that our storage capacity has been reached. That's the reason for the outage.